# Why are not pagination() and distinct() compatible?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```
$user = TW_Accounts::where('screen_name', '=', $user)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
$fllowers = $user->followings()->paginate(20);
```

And `$followers` contains 100 items. So `$followers->render()` contains `5` pages. All fine.

---

Ok, here is my new code: *(I've used `distinct()`)*

```
$fllowers = $user->followings()->distinct()->paginate(20);
```

Now `$followers` contains 18 items. But still `$followers->render()` contains `5` pages. Why?! I need to make them compatible. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [distinct() with pagination() in laravel 5.2 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283083/distinct-with-pagination-in-laravel-5-2-not-working)

Comment: what does using pagination before distinct gives ??

Comment: @Exprator It doesn't work kinda.. I've executed that for 1 minute and it's still working. Seems like a heavy query.

Comment: The use of distinct and pagination is a known bug in Laravel. I'd suggest rewriting your query. If you provide a complete example of the data and desired result, I'm sure you'll get some help.