# How can I overwrite a protected property of an object?

Tags: php, laravel

This is the result of `dd($followers)`:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#401 ▼
  #total: 144
  #lastPage: 8
  #items: Collection {#402 ▼
    #items: array:18 [▶]
  }
  #perPage: 20
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://myurl.com/SocialCenter/public/twitterprofile/JZarif"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Now I want to know, how can I overwrite `#total`? I mean I want to reinitialize it to `18`. So this is the expected result:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#401 ▼
  #total: 18
  #lastPage: 8
  #items: Collection {#402 ▼
    #items: array:18 [▶]
  }
  #perPage: 20
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://myurl.com/SocialCenter/public/twitterprofile/JZarif"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Is doing that possible?

---

Noted that none of these work:

```
$followers->total = 18;
$followers['total'] = 18;
```

Comment: Why would it change from 144 to 18? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407534/why-are-not-pagination-and-distinct-compatible)

Answer (score 3):

You could use reflection:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionObject($followers);

$property = $reflection->getProperty('total');

$property->setAccessible(true);
$property->setValue(
    $followers,
    18
);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php

Comment: What's `9001` ?

Comment: Just an arbitrary new value for the `totals` property.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a getter and setter function.

But you can use [PHP-Reflections](http://php.net/manual/de/class.reflectionclass.php). Like this example:

```
<?php
class LengthAwarePaginator
{
    private $total = true;
}

$class = new ReflectionClass("LengthAwarePaginator");
$total = $class->getProperty('total');
$total->setAccessible(true);
$total->setValue(18);
```

Comment: The property isn't accessible, you need to use http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php first.