# Laravel 5.2 - Incorrect Pagination Total When using Distinct Clause

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel-5

I have the following query where I want to select distinct rows. However the count query generated by the paginator does not seem to 
add the distinct clause and so I'm getting an incorrect total?

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

$jobs =  Job::join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'jobs.location_id')
            ->join('job_industry', 'job_industry.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
            ->select('jobs.*', 'locations.name')
            ->distinct()
            ->paginate(5, 'jobs.id');

 dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

This is the query log:

```
"query" => """
    select count(*) as aggregate from `jobs`
     inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `jobs`.`location_id`
     inner join `job_industry` on `job_industry`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id`

  """


"query" => """
    select distinct `jobs`.*, `locations`.`name` from `jobs`
     inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `jobs`.`location_id`
     inner join `job_industry` on `job_industry`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id`
    limit 5 offset 0
  """
```

As you can see the count query generated by the paginator method is incorrect - it should be `COUNT(DISTINCT jobs.id) as aggregate...`

I followed the instruction from the following post ([distinct() with pagination() in laravel 5.2 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283083/distinct-with-pagination-in-laravel-5-2-not-working)) but I cant find the following code referenced in the above post inside my copy of builder.php - this can be confirmed by checking the master repo: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L484

```
 //To solved paginator issue with distinct...
if(is_null($columns) && strpos($this->toSql(), 'distinct') !== FALSE){
    $columns = $this->columns; 
    $columns = array_filter($columns, function($value) {
        return (is_string($value) && !empty($value));
    });
}
else {
    //If null $column, set with default one
    if(is_null($columns)){
        $columns = ['*'];
    }
}
```

I tried to add the above code to my own paginate method inside the builder.php file but it makes no difference - I still get the same behavior?

How do I fix this. The only way I can overcome this is by using a group by clause but then that has its own performance issues.

Comment: Long shot here, but can you try to put inside brackets? `->paginate(5, ['jobs.id']);`

Comment: @Felippe Duarte already tried that and it doesnt work. I don't think this issue has ever been fixed reading through all these posts: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4088 unless anyone has any other suggestions?

Comment: One suggestion would be to replace the DISTINCT clause with a groupBy approach.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yeah I already mentioned that at the bottom of my post but groupby has its own performance issues and strictly speaking doesn't read well since the query isn't really doing an aggregate.

Comment: @adam78 did you ever fix this? I'm struggling with this right now.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte You saved the day here! Your example clarified another solution with * that did not work. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered similar problem before. I fixed it by doing this :

```
->distinct('jobs.id')
->paginate(5, 'jobs.id');
```

Comment: This worked for me but without needing to enter the column name into the paginate method. The distinct argument was all I needed, which is extra confusing because looking at the source code it doesn't appear to accept arguments 

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L437