# Wrong total pagination with select distinct in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 6.12, I have this request :

```
$queryJob = DB::table('jobs as j')->join('job_translations as jt', 'j.id', 'jt.job_id')
        ->whereNull('j.deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('jt.deleted_at')
        ->select('j.id', 'j.short_name', 'j.status', DB::raw("case when j.short_name = '{$request->short_name}' then 0 else 1 end"))
        ->distinct();

$jobs = $queryJob->paginate($qtyItemsPerPage);
```

The results displays an error for the total :

[image]

The total = 3, but as you can see the data contains only 2 elements.

I read here that when using a distinct, I must be clear on which column the total must be calculated: [distinct() with pagination() in laravel 5.2 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283083/distinct-with-pagination-in-laravel-5-2-not-working)

So I modified my query like that:

```
$jobs = $queryJob->paginate($qtyItemsPerPage, ['j.*']);
```

But without success, the total is still wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason for using such a complex query structure instead of using the built-in functionality of Eloquent (like relations and soft deletions)?

Comment: The simple reason I use DB facade is that ... I am beginner and do not feel confortable with Eloquent...But I think this request is not complex at all.....

Comment: can you change `distinct()` with `groupBy('j.id')` as mentioned in the article's last answer, I'm not sure if it will take the punctuation in the argument

Comment: Yes it works with a groupBy instead of a distinct. But I read in the doc that the pagination do not work with groupBy, strange.... : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results . So is it recommanded or not to use a groupBy in my case  ?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that I don't misunderstand your DB and relations structure and purpose of your query perhaps this will avoid using `distinct` or `groupBy` altogether?

```
$shortname = $request->input('short_name'); 
$queryJob = Job::with('job_translations')->select('id','short_name',
    'status', DB::raw("case when short_name = '" . $shortname . "' 
    then 0 else 1 end")
    ->paginate($qtyItemsPerPage);
```

Pagination can be easily manually added with `skip` and `take` in case you need to use groupBy

```
 $queryJob->skip(($page - 1) * $qtyItemsPerPage)->take($qtyItemsPerPage)->get();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Edwin. I am waiting a little, but I think I will keep the _groupBy_ instead of the _distinct_ . Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to pass a field name to the `distinct()` method.

With your example:

```php
$queryJob = DB::table('jobs as j')
    // joins, where and other chained methods go here
    ->distinct('j.id')
```

Solution taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69073801/3503615